# create module in python for diagonalizing matrix

Tags: python, matrix, module, python-module

For example I have a **Hermitian matrix, A** and I **Diagonalize** it with **matrix B** as:

```
A11= -0.0034
A12=  -0.007 -1j*0.0098 
A13=  -0.0112 - 1j*0.0712 
A21= A12.conjugate()
A22=  0.2162
A23=  1.062 - 1j*0.0584
A31= A13.conjugate()
A32= A23.conjugate()
A33=  2.462

A= matrix([[A11,A12,A13],[A21,A22,A23],[A31,A32,A33]])

eigenvalues_of_A, eigenvectors_of_A = numpy.linalg.eig(A);
B = eigenvectors_of_A[:,abs(eigenvalues_of_A).argsort()]          

diagonal_matrix= B.I * A * B
```

Which is straight forward.

What I want is to create a **module**. Lets say I will input 100 different **Hermitian matrices** and **import** the **module** in an existing python script to compute the 100 different **B matrices** (for each of the different inputs).

**EDIT (making my question more general)**

Reason: The reason for creating the **module** is to use it in more general purpose. By general I mean, lets say in a single python script, I have different types of matrices (for example, Hermitian matrix, real matrix, general complex matrix); now diagonalization of different types of matrices are different. so I want to create a **module** (which contains different diagonalization procedures depending on the type of the matrix) and call it whenever I need to diagonalize any matrix.

Confession: I have no idea how to create a module.

Comment: Honest question: What is an implement?

Comment: my bad, I think the appropriate word would be "module" instead of "implement".I will edit my question/title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a **dictionary** to store 100 input **Hermitian matrices** using a for loop as:

```
input_dict={}
for i in range(100):
    new_A = matrix([[A11,A12,A13],[A21,A22,A23],[A31,A32,A33]]) # new input matrix (A)
    input_dict[i] = new_A
```

After that use another dictionary to store 100 **B matrices** as:

```
B_matrices={}
for i in input_dict.keys():
    eigenvalues_of_A, eigenvectors_of_A = numpy.linalg.eig(input_dict[i]);
    B = eigenvectors_of_A[:,abs(eigenvalues_of_A).argsort()]          
    B_matrices[i] = B
```

Now, `input_matrix[i]` gives you **ith input matrix** and `B_matrices[i]` gives you corresponding **B matrix**.

You can create a module for **diagonal matrix** as:

```
def diagonalize(A):
    eigenvalues_of_A, eigenvectors_of_A = numpy.linalg.eig(A);
    B = eigenvectors_of_A[:,abs(eigenvalues_of_A).argsort()]         
    diagonal_matrix= B.I * A * B
    return diagonal_matrix
```

Now call it as:

```
diagonal_matrix = diagonalize(A)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.I am going to look into your answer now.BTW, I realized that my purpose is a bit more general,so I just edited my question,I apologize for the late edit.Hope you could help me with that too.

Comment: @string I've created a module for diagonal_matrix. Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: when I am trying to use the module you created, it is giving me the error, "'module' object has no attribute 'diagonalize' ". what am I missing? any idea?

Comment: discard my last comment, I fixed it. I think your module is exactly what I was looking for. Let me explore it a little bit more and then I am going to accept your answer. Thank you so much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a reason for using a dictionary instead of a list here?